# How can I prevent multiple records of a type are not allowed in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have four tables.

```
PERSON     DELIVERY_MAPPING       GENERATION_SYSTEM       DELIVERY_METHOD
------     ----------------       -----------------       ---------------
ID         PERSON_ID              ID                      ID
NAME       GENERATION_SYSTEM_ID   NAME                    NAME
                                  DELIVERY_METHOD_ID      IS_SPECIAL
```

Example data:

```
PERSON     DELIVERY_MAPPING       GENERATION_SYSTEM       DELIVERY_METHOD
------     ----------------       -----------------       ---------------
1. TOM       1    1               1. COLOR PRINTER 1      1. EMAIL    N
2. DICK      1    2               2. BW PRINTER    1      2. POST     N
3. HARRY     2    3               3. HANDWRITTEN   3      3. PIGEONS  Y
```

A `DELIVERY_METHOD` contains ways to deliver new letters — `EMAIL`, `POST`, `PIGEON`. The `IS_SPECIAL` column marks a record as a means of a special delivery. It is indicated by a simple value of `Y` or `N`. Only `PIGEON` is a special delivery method i.e. `Y`, the others are not i.e. `N`.

The `GENERATION_SYSTEM` has the information that will finally print the letter. Example values are `COLOR PRINTER` and `DOT MATRIX PRINTER`. Each `GENERATION_SYSTEM` will always be delivered using one of the `DELIVERY_METHOD`s. There's a foreign key-between `GENERATION_SYSTEM` and `DELIVERY_METHOD`.

Now, each `PERSON` can have his letters generated by different `GENERATION_SYSTEM`s and since, it is a many-to-many relation, we have the `DELIVERY_MAPPING` table and that's that's why we have foreign key's on both ends.

So far, so good.

I need to ensure that it if a person has his letters generated by a system that uses a special delivery method then he cannot be allowed to have multiple generation systems in the mappings list. For example, Dick can't have his letters generated using the colour printer because he already gets all his handwritten letters delivery by a pigeon (which is a marked a special delivery method).

How would I accomplish such a constraint? I tried doing it with a before-insert-or-update trigger on the `DELIVERY_MAPPING` table but that causes the mutating trigger problem when updating.

Can is normalise this scenario even more? Maybe it is just that i haven't normalised my table properly.

Either way, I'd love to hear your take on this issue. I hope I've been verbose enough (...and if you can propose a better title for this post, that would be great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW special_queues_mv
  NOLOGGING
  CACHE
  BUILD IMMEDIATE 
  REFRESH ON COMMIT 
  ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
     AS SELECT dmap.person_id
             , SUM(DECODE(dmet.is_special, 'Y', 1, 0)) AS special_queues
             , SUM(DECODE(dmet.is_special, 'N', 1, 0)) AS regular_queues
          FROM delivery_mapping dmap
             , generation_system gsys
             , delivery_method dmet
         WHERE dmap.generation_system_id = gsys.id
           AND gsys.delevery_method_id = dmet.id
         GROUP
            BY dmap.person_id
/

  ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW special_queues_mv
    ADD ( CONSTRAINT special_queues_mv_chk1 CHECK ((special_queues = 1 AND regular_queues = 0) OR ( regular_queues > 0 AND special_queues = 0 ) ) ENABLE VALIDATE)
/
```

That's how I did it. DazzaL's answer gave me a hint on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For a complicated constraint like this, I think you need to use triggers.  I don't think the mutating table problem is an issue, because you are either going to do an update or do nothing.

The only table you need to worry about is `Delivery_Mapping`.  Before allowing a change to this table, you need to run a query on the existing table to get the number of specials and gs's:

```
select SUM(case when dme.is_special = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as NumSpecial,
       count(distinct gs.id) as NumGS,
       MIN(gs.id) as GSID
from delivery_mapping dm join
     generation_system gs
     on dm.generation_system_id = gs.id join
     delivery_method dme
     on gs.delivery_method_id = dme.id
where dm.person_id = PERSONID
```

With this information, you can check if the insert/update can proceed.  I think you need to 
check the conditions:

- If NumSpecial = 0 and the new delivery method is not special, then proceed.
- If NumSpecial = 0 and NumGS = 0, then proceed.
- Otherwise fail.

The logic is a bit more complicated for updates.

By the way, I prefer to wrap updates/inserts/deletes in stored procedures, so logic like this doesn't get hidden in triggers.  I find that debugging and maintaining procedures is much easier than dealing with triggers, which may be possibly cascading.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I did manage to accomplish the `INSERT`s myself but it was the `UPDATE`s that cause the mutating trigger issue. A colleague of mine said that this is solvable using a compound a trigger with three parts — a before statement-level trigger to initiate a trigger variable, a for-each-row trigger to populate the variable with the list of identifiers and an after statement-level trigger to validate the rows in the variable and throw an exception/rollback if the conditions are not met. Thoughts?

Comment: I think you can query the database before making the change and see if the change is going to cause a problem.  I don't believe three triggers are necessary.  But the logic might be a big complicated.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla - you can do this with a compound trigger, but I would follow Gordon's advice of implementing this via a stored procedure. In either case, you'll need to serialize the inserts. Otherwise two sessions starting at the same time will both pass the check, but can insert data that violates the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid triggers on the base tables for this unless you can guarantee serialization.

you could use an API (best way) as Gordon says (again, be sure to serialize) or if that isn't suitable, use a materialized view (we don't need to serialize here, as the check is done on commit):

```
SQL> create materialized view log on person with rowid, primary key including new values;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> create materialized view log on delivery_mapping with rowid, primary key including new values;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> create materialized view log on generation_system with rowid, primary key (delivery_method_id) including new values;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> create materialized view log on delivery_method with rowid, primary key (is_special) including new values;

Materialized view log created.
```

we create a materialized view to show the counts of special + non special links for each user:

```
SQL> create materialized view check_del_method
  2  refresh fast on commit
  3  with primary key
  4  as
  5  select pers.id, count(case del_meth.is_special when 'Y' then 1 end) special_count,
  6         count(case del_meth.is_special when 'N' then 1 end) non_special_count
  7    from person pers
  8         inner join delivery_mapping del_map
  9                 on pers.id = del_map.person_id
 10         inner join generation_system gen
 11                 on gen.id = del_map.generation_system_id
 12         inner join delivery_method del_meth
 13                 on del_meth.id = gen.delivery_method_id
 14   group by pers.id;

Materialized view created.
```

the MView is defined as fast refresh on commit, so the modified rows are rebuilt on commit. now the rule is that if special+non special counts are non-zero, that's an error condition.

```
SQL> create trigger check_del_method_aiu
  2  after insert or update on check_del_method
  3  for each row
  4  declare
  5  begin
  6    if (:new.special_count > 0 and :new.non_special_count > 0)
  7    then
  8      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cannot have a mix of special and non special delivery methods for user ' || :new.id);
  9   end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> insert into delivery_mapping values (1, 3);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-20000: Cannot have a mix of special and non special delivery methods for
user 1
ORA-06512: at "TEST.CHECK_DEL_METHOD_AIU", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TEST.CHECK_DEL_METHOD_AIU'
```

Comment: DazzaL, thanks for your response. I got inspiration from your answer and it turned out even simpler. Please have a look at my answer. I'd like to hear your thoughts as why you needed multiple materialised views.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla but I only had 1 mat view. (only 4 logs, which are needed to track the base tables)